# Python Scrape Issue - Sublime, Chrome

Tags: python, selenium

First off - no experience with Python, Sublime Text or Selenium - please be kind..

I am having an issue building a scraper in Python - using Sublime text, Selenium and Chrome. I have updated to the latest Python, Pip and downloaded the correct Chrome Driver. The webpage pops up fine, but get errors.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from selenium.webdriver.common.ui import WebDriverWait - commented out due to error
#from selenium.webdriver.common import expected_conditions as EC - commented out due to error
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get ("https://www.royalcaribbean.com/account/cruise-planner/category/pt_beverage/product/3222?bookingId=1429192&shipCode=NV&sailDate=20220907")
print(driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='ng-tns-c210-4 text-promo-1').text)***
```

Comment: What errors?  Which line?  Do not make us guess.  It's always best to post the entire traceback.

Comment: I will note that that page takes 4 or 5 seconds to load.  You're not waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.royalcaribbean.com/account/cruise-planner/category/pt_beverage/product/3222?bookingId=1429192&shipCode=NV&sailDate=20220907")
elem=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.ng-tns-c210-4.text-promo-1')))
print(elem.text)
```

Your class name is actually multiple class names so using css selector.

Outputs:

```
$80.99
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code above as well as the Imports and get this reponse:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\tutorial1.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
NameError: name 'webdriver' is not defined
[Finished in 406ms]

Error in Line 8 : driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

Comment: a little odd that error comes from not having "from selenium import webdriver"

Comment: I did, but since I am new i need to get 15 reputations before it shows.

Comment: Oh that's an upvote if you look underneath it it's the checkmark.